Resolving dependency conflict

I am trying to resolve dependency conflict but unable to do so provide complete guidance. Why does this issue occur, and how to resolve it?
When I add the intl version :0.19.0, I get an error

Resolving dependencies...

Because month_year_picker <0.3.0+1 depends on intl ^0.17.0 and rms depends on intl ^0.19.0, month_year_picker <0.3.0+1 is forbidden.
So, because rms depends on month_year_picker ^0.2.0+3, version solving failed.

you can add month_year_picker from github also there are some pull requests in which it has been updated to use intel 0.19.0

In the pubspec.yaml file you could try to add this to force using 0.19.0
dependency_overrides:
  intl: ^0.19.0

Although, there is a small risk that it then crashes because of the library using 0.17.0 using something that doesn't exist in 0.19.0 but I think this is very unlikely.

but what i do i really want (month_year_picker  dependency) as well because this dependency is used in very wide range in project.

@IrfaShaw I'm not saying anything about not using that anymore. Just add the lines in pubspec.yaml that I said
